# Store list of rows as list of dictionary as a column in dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
import sys
import boto3
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col,expr

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])





sc = SparkContext()
#sc.setLogLevel('DEBUG')
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

#logger = glueContext.get_logger()
#logger.DEBUG('Hello Glue')
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)





d = [
 {"account_number": 1, "v1": 100830, "v2": 1000},
 {"account_number": 2, "v1": 2000, "v2": None},
 {"account_number": 2, "v1": 4545, "v2": 55},
  {"account_number": 3, "v1": 4545, "v2": 55},
  {"account_number": 3, "v1": 555, "v2": 55}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(d)
df.show()
```

I want to come up column storing list of row as list of dictionary for the rows having same account number ( group by account number).

As a second step I need to pass this new column to some UDF function only once for each account but the result should be updated on all rows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`window, to_json, collect_list, struct`** in built spark functions for this.

**Example:**

```
d = [
 {"account_number": 1, "v1": 100830, "v2": 1000},
 {"account_number": 2, "v1": 2000, "v2": None},
 {"account_number": 2, "v1": 4545, "v2": 55},
  {"account_number": 3, "v1": 4545, "v2": 55},
  {"account_number": 3, "v1": 555, "v2": 55}
]
wind= Window.partitionBy("account_number")
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)
df.withColumn("new_column",to_json(collect_list(struct(col("v1"),col("v2"))).over(wind))).show(10,False)

#output
#+--------------+------+----+----------------------------------------+
#|account_number|v1    |v2  |new_column                              |
#+--------------+------+----+----------------------------------------+
#|1             |100830|1000|[{"v1":100830,"v2":1000}]               |
#|2             |2000  |null|[{"v1":2000},{"v1":4545,"v2":55}]       |
#|2             |4545  |55  |[{"v1":2000},{"v1":4545,"v2":55}]       |
#|3             |4545  |55  |[{"v1":4545,"v2":55},{"v1":555,"v2":55}]|
#|3             |555   |55  |[{"v1":4545,"v2":55},{"v1":555,"v2":55}]|
#+--------------+------+----+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hello @notNull Thanks for giving idea . I changed it little bit to make it more generic.`df = spark.createDataFrame(d)
df.show()
wind= Window.partitionBy("account_number")
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)
expr1 = "map(" + ",".join([f"'{c}',`{c}`" for c in df.columns]) + ")"
df.withColumn("new_column",collect_list( expr(expr1)).over(wind)).show(truncate=False)`

Comment: Please open this as new question!

Comment: I just want to confirm it is working. Thanks for help .We don't need separate question . Your guidance helped me to solve this problem